# Are "x" and "u" printf/scanf conversion specifiers equally applicable to the same types?

Tags: c++, c, printf, format-specifiers

Suppose I have

```
printf("%llu %llx", one, two);
```

and then both `one` and `two` can be of type `unsigned long long` and the difference will be just that they are printed as decimal or hexadecimal respectively.

There's a whole bunch of width specifiers (`h`, `hh`, `L`, `I`, etc) and looks like each of them can be used with both `u` and `x` conversion specifier but each time I'm allowed to pass values of unsigned type of the right width.

Is it true than no matter if it ends in `x` or in `u` with the same width specifier in front I can pass values of the same time and it'll always be legal?

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, sure, and I'm looking for a catch.

Comment: Well `x`/`X` and `u` (and `o`) all have the same types for each width specifier. Isn't that what you're asking?

Comment: There's no catch. (And the same is true of `e`, `f` and `g` format specifiers: a given datum can be presented in different ways.)

Comment: `o`, `u`, `x`, and `X` all expect the same argument type for a given width specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it true than no matter if it ends in `x` or in `u` with the same width specifier in front I can pass values of the same time and it'll always be legal?

Yes, if a width specifier is valid for use with one of those then it is valid for use with both, and also with `o` and `X`, and the resulting directives serve the same data type -- an unsigned integer of the specified width.  The only difference is the way the output is formatted (or for `scanf`, the format that is expected of the input).

> There's a whole bunch of width specifiers (`h`, `hh`, `L`, `I`, etc) and looks
>   like each of them can be used with both u and x conversion specifier
>   but each time I'm allowed to pass values of unsigned type of the right
>   width.

There indeed is a wide variety of width specifiers.  Most, but not all, of them are applicable to and intended for integer types, both the unsigned ones corresponding to `x`, `X`, `o`, and `u` and the signed ones corresponding to `d` and `i`.  The standard does not specify `L` among those, however, and it does not specify `I` at all.  Some implementations might nevertheless accept those as integer width specifiers, with implementation-specific behavior.